# ¿Como Llenar dos tablas con una llave foranea en común?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en PHP, donde tengo dos tablas usuarios y empresa. donde los campos de usuarios son:
idUsuario, NombreUsuario, Users, Pass, fechareg, estado.
y la tabla Empresa
IdEmpresa, TelEmpresa, Email, idUsuario.

Donde quiero hacer un formulario de registro incluyendo campos de ambas tablas para que se llenen a la vez, mi pregunta es ¿Como haria para que al llenar el campo IdUsuario de la tabla empresa se llena a la vez con el IdUsuario de la tabla Usuario, si este último es AutoIncrementado y como podria hacer la sentencia en SQL.

Comment: Considera leer [ask], tu pregunta puede acabar cerrada, llevas algo hecho al momento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando la clase PDO de PHP, https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php, dentro del bloque try - catch y con dentro de una transacción, realizar primero un INSERT de la tabla Usuarios, posteriormente sacar el id del usuario insertado con método lastInsertId https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php y utilizarlo en la última inserción para la tabla empresa.

```html
$pdo = new PDO(....);
try
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    
    $sql_insert_usuarios = "INSERT INTO usuarios ...";
    $smt_insert_usuarios = $pdo->prepare($sql_insert_usuarios);
    $smt_insert_usuarios->execute(array(...));
    
    $id_usuario = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    
    $sql_insert_empresa = "INSERT INTO empresa ...";
    $smt_insert_empresa = $pdo->prepare($sql_insert_empresa);
    $smt_insert_empresa->execute(array(...)); //Aquí puedes pasar el id_usuario
    
    $pdo->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $pdo->rollback();
}
```